# show pictures from db in modal nodejs

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

I have this code

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-pic-id="1">
        <img alt="" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97300&w=400&h=300">
    </a>
</div>
```

it opens a modal window that contains the ID of the picture I want to show from the DB.

this code is inside picutres.ejs, how can I send a command to the server.js to get me the details for this picture depending on the picture ID?

```
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
    var picID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('pic-id');
    $("#image").attr("src","http://localhost/chat/images/" + picID + ".jpg");
});
```

Comment: * I need to run a loop in the body section that runs over my MySQL table, and print depending on pictures amount another <div class="col-lg..." for each picture.

Comment: So pictures are stored on the public ftp and you have MySQL db additionally to store some informations about those pictures, right?